# Jquery validate custom rules: When a checkbox click, a textbox required

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

How to set the rule so that :

for a checkbox a, when it is clicked, the textbox a is required

And the number of checkbox is flexible , i can not define the checkbox one by one

But the number of checkbox is equal to  textbox , that is for sure

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, you render check boxes along with text boxes.So these two will  always be equal to each other. So when you click on check box, automatically its pair textbox will also be present.Otherwise, no check box will be rendered without the textbox.That way you can avoid one more checking.Hope this will help you.